# Correct way to block a site if a cookie isn't present apache 2.4

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, http-cookie

I'm using apache 2.4.12 (Ubunutu 15.10) as an oauth2 proxy behind a node app. The app sends lots of unauthenticated requests before login b/c it doesn't know it's not authenticated (it doesn't know/care about the proxy) which creates lots of large cookies which can cause issues.

What I'd like to do is say if a particular cookie doesn't exist (mod_auth_openidc_session) -- which means it hasn't auth'd yet -- block all requests to my server. So far I have this but I'm not sure if this is correct (since the condition takes time to repro):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mod_auth_openidc_session
RewriteRule .*my.server.com.* [F]
```

Is this doing what I want?:

Block all requests to http(s)://my.server.com/ or http(s)://my.server.com/login etc unless the cookie mod_auth_openidc_session is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overall goal strikes me as odd, but with respect to your rewrite recipe, the `RewriteRule` directive is wrong.  The general syntax is `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`, where the Pattern marches against the path in the url, but since your matching is fine by the rewrite Cond rule you might just want `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [F]`.  If you do want to match only the one host, then that needs another RewriteCond rule to match against `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: Thanks so much. There were two useful points here. Obviously answering how to do the rewrite but then also pointing out having more rewrite conditions is a good idea. So, putting it all together this was good for me: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.server\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mod_auth_openidc_session
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/websocketpath            [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [F,L,NC]`

Comment: If you just want to pass the URL through unchanged then it's preferable to simply use a hyphen for the substitution, ie. `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` - no need for the `L` or `NC` flags here (`F` implies `L`).